# meteor run android one error GroupMarkerNotSet

Tags: android, meteor, emulation

when I do the meteor run android in my project it threw one error:

```
I20160721-10:16:07.017(8)? 07-21 10:16:06.241 21476 21510 E chromium:
 [ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(340)]
 [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:F8B8574C237F0000]GL ERROR
 :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL
 command
```

And the link on the android emulator screen can not click in,it has no action at all when click the links of the blue characters,the detail screen is in the attached picture.                                                                                 [android emulator screen of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W70m.png)